# AngularJS directive link does not work in Firefox

Tags: angularjs

I have an icon that is simply a link to the login page:

http://myhost.com:3000/book#/login

jade: `a(href='#/login')`

It works fine in Chrome and Safari, but firefox does not react to it at all... anyone knows why?

Comment: Can you show the code that you are using to set up your routes?

Comment: .config(['$routeProvider', 
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      ...
      .when('/login', {
        templateUrl: '../partials/login', 
        login: true
      })

Comment: Might related to this https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8263